# .NET Image.Save() ignores TIFF Property Items that have been changed

Tags: .net, tiff

Situation: I have a file that contains text data and many TIFF images in binary. There are a few tiff property tags that I need to change because they are being configured wrong when the tiff was originally created before they were put in that file. So, I dump the binary data to a byte[], then to a MemoryStream, and then to an Image, and then proceed to remove all PropertyItems from Image.PropertyItems and then recreate my own tags via Image.SetPropertyItem(). Finally, I do an Image.Save() with the correct encoder info and encoder parameters.

Problem: The file that gets created does not contain all of the property items I created AND some of the items I change have been completely ignored. The data types in property items have been ignored as well (short was changed to long, etc.). It's like Image.Save() rewrites whatever the hell it wants. To be more specific, I'm specifying ImageWith and ImageLength properties to be SHORT and theyre being written as LONG. And the PlanarConfig property item is not even being written at all.

Here's some of my code: (Any idea why this would be happening and how to fix it?)

```
const int SHORT = 3;
const int SHORT_LEN = 2;
const int LONG = 4;
const int LONG_LEN = 4;
const int RATIONAL = 5;
const int RATIONAL_LEN = 8;

byte[] bytesFront = bco.Records[0].Fields[4].Data;
byte[] bytesRear = bco.Records[0].Fields[6].Data;
MemoryStream msFront = new MemoryStream(bytesFront);
Bitmap imgFront = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(msFront);

PropertyItem pi = imgFront.GetPropertyItem(imgFront.PropertyIdList.First<int>());

foreach (PropertyItem currentPropertyItem in imgFront.PropertyItems)
{
    imgFront.RemovePropertyItem(currentPropertyItem.Id);
}

// SubFile Type
pi.Id = 254;
pi.Type = LONG;
pi.Len = LONG_LEN;
pi.Value = GetBytes((uint)0);
imgFront.SetPropertyItem(pi);

// Image Width
pi.Id = 256;
pi.Type = SHORT;
pi.Len = SHORT_LEN;
pi.Value = GetBytes((ushort)imgFront.Width);
imgFront.SetPropertyItem(pi);

//...

// Planar Config
pi.Id = 284;
pi.Type = SHORT;
pi.Len = SHORT_LEN;
pi.Value = GetBytes((ushort)1);
imgFront.SetPropertyItem(pi);

// Resolution Unit
pi.Id = 296;
pi.Type = SHORT;
pi.Len = SHORT_LEN;
pi.Value = GetBytes((ushort)2);
imgFront.SetPropertyItem(pi);

ImageCodecInfo encoderInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(i => i.MimeType == "image/tiff");
EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);

imgFront.Save(@"C:\Temp\imgFront.tif", encoderInfo, encoderParameters);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I learned that maybe the .NET Framework isn't the ultimate authority in TIFFs and it actually does do whatever it wants to. And there is little you can do to control it. I ended up learning to use LibTiff.NET and used the following code to do what I needed:

```
byte[] bytesOriginal = bco.Records[0].Fields[4].Data;
MemoryStream streamOriginal = new MemoryStream(bytesOriginal);

streamOriginal.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Tiff tiffMemory = Tiff.ClientOpen("In-Memory", "r", streamOriginal, new TiffStream());
Tiff tiffFile = Tiff.Open(@"C:\Temp\imgTest2.tif", "w");

tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.SUBFILETYPE, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.SUBFILETYPE).First());
tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH).First());
tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH).First());
tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE).First());
tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION).First());
tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC).First());
tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.STRIPOFFSETS, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.STRIPOFFSETS).First());
tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.ORIENTATION, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.ORIENTATION).First());
tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL).First());
tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.ROWSPERSTRIP, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.ROWSPERSTRIP).First());
tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.STRIPBYTECOUNTS, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.STRIPBYTECOUNTS).First());
tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.XRESOLUTION, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.XRESOLUTION).First());
tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.YRESOLUTION, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.YRESOLUTION).First());
tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.PLANARCONFIG, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.PLANARCONFIG).First());
tiffFile.SetField(TiffTag.RESOLUTIONUNIT, tiffMemory.GetField(TiffTag.RESOLUTIONUNIT).First());

tiffFile.CheckpointDirectory();

byte[] bytesNew = new byte[tiffMemory.RawStripSize(0)];
tiffMemory.ReadRawStrip(0, bytesNew, 0, bytesNew.Length);
tiffFile.WriteRawStrip(0, bytesNew, bytesNew.Length);

tiffMemory.Close();
tiffFile.Close();
```